# Return multiple "roles" from JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, datatables

I am trying to return multiple "roles" to a DataTable. Every single role has a specific "title" and "class", which then is returned to the datatable column.

```
var $role_number = full['roles'];
var $roles = {
    1: { title: 'WorkShop Leader', class: 'badge-light-primary' },
    2: { title: 'Planner', class: 'badge-light-secondary' },
    3: { title: 'Operator', class: 'badge-light-warning' },
};
```

These are the roles available. And then I return this:

```
return (
    '<span class="badge rounded-pill ' + $roles[$role_number].class + '">' + 
    $roles[$role_number].title + '</span>'
);
```

This works if the JSON Object has only one role (for example, role 1: WorkShop Leader).
But I want "roles" to be an array, because one user can have more than one role.

So this user has only one role:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Albert",
    "second_name": "Cognoms",
    "roles": [1],
    "status": 1
}
```

And it works properly:
[image]

But this user has two roles, and it doesn't show both badges:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Albert",
    "second_name": "Cognoms",
    "roles": [1, 2],
    "status": 1
}
```

[image]

If someone knows a better way to display role badges using an array, I would really appreciate the help. I know the solution must be something easy, but I can't get my mind clear on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you just initialise a variable called, say, badges then use a for(const role_number of user.roles) loop to append badges with the relevant element?

Comment: You mean looping into the roles of the user, and adding to badges "title" and "class" for each role (1, 2, 3)? Because that's what I'm trying to do, but without success at all.

Comment: Yeah, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/728mywv4/

Comment: Yes, this works, I store the badges for each user, but I can't return those badges to the column, it still displays 1,2. https://jsfiddle.net/81wnrbdx/

Comment: Solved. It was returning "undefined", but now it properly returns the badges. Thanks for the help!